# Indexing a nested type as a string in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I've encountered an issue I'm having with the TypeScript compiler where I'm trying to index any type with a string. I'm much more familiar with dynamic programming languages (read: Python) where I can easily do this with a dictionary.

Let's say I have two types:

```
type PageLoadedType = {
  page: {
    pageTitle: string;
    pageName: string;
  }
}
type ButtonClickType = {
  buttonClick: {
    location: string;
    buttonName: string;
  }
}
```

And I have these two types combined into EventTypes to assign to a variable:

```
type EventTypes = PageLoadedType | ButtonClickType | undefined;
```

Now I have a variable assigned as an event type and I want to iterate through the nested object to get to the children and strip characters from the child strings. So:

```
let myEvent: EventTypes = {
  buttonClick: {
    location: 'Chicago, Illinois',
    buttonName: 'submit-location'
  }
}
Object.keys(myEvent as {}).forEach((key) => {
  Object.keys(myEvent[key]).forEach((innerKey) => {
    myEvent[key][innerKey] = myEvent[key][innerKey].slice(0,5)
  }
}
```

My issue is that the compiler complains and states:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to in
> dex type 'PageLoadedType | ButtonClickType'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PageLoadedType |
> ButtonClickType'

How can I get around this and what is a "best practice" solution? I'm sure I'm missing something simple since I'm new to TypeScript. Please note that I cannot allow the compiler to accept the keyword 'any'.

Comment: Your TypeScript playground link appears mangled. I don't think you'll be able to get this working with your `EventTypes` design. Furthermore, the `|| undefined` inside `Object.keys()` is an error. It's invalid to call the latter with such a value.

Comment: Apologies for the TypeScript Playground issue. Not sure why it didn't store the code, but you can copy/paste it in if you'd like. That's a fair point, but the larger issue is the iteration over the type. Any comment on that?

Comment: As I said, I don't think it'll work with the way `EventTypes` has been defined. `Object.keys(...)` produces values which are typed as arbitrary `string`. `EventTypes` isn't defined as an index type (e.g. `{ [key: string]: ... }`), so the compiler complains that it can't simply accept any old `string` as an indexing value. I suspect what you probably want to do instead is have `EventTypes = Partial<PageLoadedType> & Partial<ButtonClickType>`.

Comment: Okay, I've tried that and receive the same compiler complaint. Hmm.